# How to send multiple json body using jmeter?

Tags: rest, post, jmeter

I have written a REST API and now my requirement is to send the multiple JSON body to the API using POST method from JMeter. I have a csv file with four values(1,2,3,4). And in each of the four files I have the JSON body. I used :

Step-1) [added the csv file to jmeter and create a reference and named it JSON_FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ5IG.png)

Step-2) `${__FileToString(C:Path_to_csv_file/${__eval(${JSON_FILE})}.txt,,)}`

But from this I am able to access only first file i.e which is named with one. How do I send the body of all file to the API?
Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Body data as follows in HTTP Sampler:

```
{__FileToString(${JSON_FILE},,)}
```

You have to put all the file path in your `plan.csv` file. At each line, there should be a file path.

**Example:**

Suppose, you have 4 files with JSON body which you want to use in your HTTP sampler.

Give the file path of these 4 files in your CSV file which is `plan.csv`. Each line contains a file path like this:

```
/User/file/file1.json
/User/file/file2.json
/User/file/file3.json
/User/file/file4.json
```

Now, in your CSV data set config, Use the proper file name of CSV file which contains all the file path and give it a variable name like `JSON_FILE`.

Now, Use `{__FileToString(${JSON_FILE},,)}` this line in your Body data. Also use the loop count value accordingly.

Comment: Thanks . But I am  getting the error as :
Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@23112ca0; line: 1, column: 3]

Comment: Show your csv data set and make sure all the file contains valid JSON.

Comment: 1st csv dataset:
{
   
    "data":{
     "A":"B",
     "day":"Mon"
    }
}


2nd csv dataset:
{
   
    "data":{
     "A":"B",
     "day":"Tue"
    }
}

These both datasets are working with Postman if I hit them individually but it is not working with Jmeter and giving the above error

Comment: These are the file contents. Show your csv data set where you put the file path for 1st csv dataset, 2nd csv dataset and so on.

Comment: I did nothing but just I have a file named plans.csv and entry is placed like this :
1
2
where 1 and 2 are the files names of two files.

Comment: Thats the problem, You should place file path in your `plan.csv` file not the file name. Each file path should reside in a new line at `plan.csv` file. Already explained it in my answer with example. Thanks!

Comment: No , it is still giving the same error . I gave the complete path in the csv file , but same error.

Comment: Why don't you share the complete scenario with screenshots so that I can help!

Comment: I have a REST api for post request and my requirement is to hit the api with 2 different json bodies simultaneously . For that thing I have to json files which I shared and have the path of those two files in csv file . So I created a request , created the csv dataset as shown above but it is giving me the error . So how do I hit the API with these different bodies simultaneously ?

Comment: I understand your requirements and already gave the answer for it. It works for me and your set up looks fine also. Now, debug properly if you had missed something in your test plan. i.e HTTP sampler, body data, requests, response, csvdata set config, json files etc. But the possible reason is, your JSON data is wrong! So double check your JSON data. Can you show your requests tab after test run in view results tree listener? What is sent to the server?As long as you able to send the JSON data from different file, you achieved your requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use CSV Data Set Config as it will read the next value for each thread (virtual user) and/or [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration.

If your requirement is to send all the files bodies at once you can go for an alternative approach

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which you use for sending the JSON payload
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def builder = new StringBuilder()
   new File('/path/to/plans.csv').readLines().each { line ->
       builder.append(new File(line).text).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
   }
   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', builder.toString(), '')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```

   the above code iterates through entries in `plans.csv` file, reads the file contents into a string and concatenates them altogether. Once done it sets the HTTP Request sampler body data to the generated cumulative string.

Check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) to learn more and what else could be achieved using Groovy scripting in JMeter.